# https works fine but *.com:443 gives a 400 error?

Tags: html, apache, ssl, https

I've got a site up (apache centos) that has no issues connecting over https but when I try to call a page with the 443 port defined ie example.com:443 I get a 400 error.

I've looked at the httpd.conf and listen 443 is uncommented.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `http://` or `https://` when entering the address?

Comment: http:// The reason being is that we're getting a response from an API to our server with the address of the http:// .. example.com:443/foo.php?auth=12345 variety. Is the call at fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way **`http`**`://www.example.com` is the same as going for **`http`**`://www.example.com`**`:80`**

You will see that 
 **`https`**`://www.example.com` equals **`https`**`://www.example.com`**`:443`**

What is probably happening to you is you are trying:

**`http`**`://www.example.com`**`:443`** (that is, plain HTTP protocol, but over the 443 port).

### Why is this a problem?

The web server expects ***SSL-encrypted data*** on the 443 port.

When you use **`http`**`://www.example.com`**`:443`**, you're telling your browser to **speak plain HTTP** to 443, an usually SSL-enabled server port.

The result is unpredictable. It ultimately depends on the server.

Most servers will either **(1)** kill the connection right off the bat or **(2)** just give back a `HTTP 400 Bad request` response, trying to let you know **you** did something wrong (the `4xx` group of errors indicates **client** errors).

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I'll contact the API manager and ask why their app is sending an http :// example.com:443 link back as a signed URL.

Comment: No problem. I added an SSL explanation. Check the answer again, hope it is more accurate and clear now. It really seems the API manager made a mistake sending HTTP:443 in the address. Cheers!