# 200 ok followed by 400 Bad Request error page http://domainname:443

Tags: apache, plesk

server is running Parallels Plesk Panel 11.5.30 and httpd-2.2.15-39 when any website is accessed using url http://website_domain_name:443 it show error page 400 Bad Request but with 200 OK header.

I already have read this question but can't find answer. 
[https works fine but *.com:443 gives a 400 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409124/https-works-fine-but-com443-gives-a-400-error)

Answer (score 0):

http://domainname:443

Not secure HTTP proto over secure port?

Maybe it should be

http**S**://domainname:443 ?

or you have to sure that 443 port is actually not secure.

Comment: I know its hould be https:// but some how google decicded to access this page and now its indexed on http://

Comment: I am asking for a solution where i can fix there response header. or kill the connection so such pages are nor served.

Comment: Look around for redirects / rewrites in .htaccess or web server vhost config.

Comment: this request is not reaching .htaccess as server is showing default 400 bad request page. I will check if i can find a solution in vhost config.